# inno setup Aplicación de 16 bits no compatible

Tags: c#, .net

Estoy continuando un proyecto en .NET 4.7.2 que detecta y descarga las actualizaciones; al compilarlo con inno Setup el compilado se completa correctamen, pero al subir la actualización y que el sistema lo descargue me aparece el siguiente error

> Aplicación de 16 bits no compatible
> El programa o característica "??\C:\Users\Sistemas\AppData\Local\Temp\Sistemasmart.exe" no se puede iniciar o ejecutar porque no es compatible con versiones de 64 bits de Windows. Consulta con el fabricante de software si existe una versión disponible que sea compatible con Windows de 64 bits.

Ya consulté con el desarrollador anterior pero no pudimos solucionarlo, pero algo curioso es que si el instalador generado por inno setup es ejecutado directamente la instalación se lleva a cabo sin problemas